# Jar file not running on mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, jar, runnable

I have made a runnable java file on eclipse on my windows 64 bit computer using jre and jdk 8. The runnable file opens on my windows computer and on my desktop windows computer. When i email the jar file over to my mac, the jar file does not work and it gives the error the java jar file "snoman3.jar" could not be launched. I ran it through the terminal and still gives the same error. I have jre 8 on my mac yet it is still not running. There are many duplicates of this question but i could not find a solution that worked for me, may somebody please tell me possible solutions for this? PS I am running OS X yosemite on my mac. 
The following is the error I am getting. PS I am using the libGDX graphics library.

```
 java -jar snoman3.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /var/folders/88/wtc6dz2d5tvdr3qnzb3pq69w0000gn/T/libgdxasma/75260a42/liblwjgl.dylib
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1817)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1083)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:70)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112)
    at org.lwjgl.openal.AL.<clinit>(AL.java:59)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.openal.OpenALAudio.<init>(OpenALAudio.java:70)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.<init>(LwjglApplication.java:81)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.<init>(LwjglApplication.java:63)
    at com.rarster.snowman.Main.main(Main.java:15)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: What happens when you do `java -jar snoman3.jar` on the command line? What is the exact error output?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put the error, it is there now. In addition, I am using a graphics library called libGDX.

Comment: has the `snoman3` application been developed on a newer Java version than what you currently have? Try `java -version` from your  terminal.

Comment: The native library needed by libgdx is missing, misidentified, corrupt, not marked executable, or incompatible with yosemite.  Once you use jni libraries, java is no longer platform independent.  I suggest you try building a sample gdx project *on* a yosemite mac and work forward from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are getting a `NullPointerException` behind the scenes. `InvocationTargetException` is just a wrapper for an exception that's thrown within a dynamic invocation.

If I saw your code, I could have helped you more.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /var/folders/88/wtc6dz2d5tvdr3qnzb3pq69w0000gn/T/libgdxasma/75260a42/liblwjgl.dylib. Looks like some LibGDX library that the .jar needs is missing.

Comment: Either way, either the package is corrupt or the code has not been written in such a manner to call the right resources.

Comment: What do you mean by code has not been written in such a manner because the code compiled properly on a windows, would anything change if it runs on a mac?

Comment: Also I have about 8 different classes in my code, should I give you the main one that is called first?

Comment: No, this is a problem with a platform specific jni library or one of its dependencies.

Comment: @ChrisStratton is there a way to fix this jni issue without having to explode the jar and repackage the project?

Comment: @Rarster let ChrisStratton respond. Otherwise you would have to debug the code.

Comment: I don't know, I suspect it will be challenging other than on the target system, but extracting the dylib from the zip (jar) and running whatever osx uses in place of ldd on it could be interesting.  I'd check for yosemite issue reports on the libgdx site/lists, too.

Comment: @Rarster guess you'd have to start debugging.

Comment: @ChrisStratton What does OS X use in the place of Idd? And mohammad, should I give you my "MyGdxGame" class, the class that is called first in my program?

Comment: @Rarster email me the whole project as a ZIP. mohammad.mnajar@gmail.com